# Control position of validation label

Tags: flutter

When using Form validator the default position of the message label is on the bottom, is there a way to put it on the top of the Text field?
[image]

Comment: I am not sure that it is possible. Maybe you should make your own TextField with [FormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField-class.html)

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why they didn't include some kind of placement control since that's what most users will need to do most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change position on validation label in TextFormField

But you can build your own `TextFormField` by using `FormField` widget and custumize its children to look like a normal `TextFormField` this is a working example made with `FormField`

```
FormField(
    // initialValue: 0,
    autovalidate: true,
    validator: normalValidator,
    builder: (state) {
    state.validate();
      return Column(
       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

                  children: <Widget>[
         state.errorText!=null? Text(state.errorText, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 12),):Container(),
                            DropdownButton(
                                isExpanded: true,
                                value: state.value,
                                items: _choices,
                                onChanged: (v) {
                                  state.didChange(v);
                                  setState((){});
                                }),

                          ],
                        );
                      }),
```

You can now customize it to sweet your needs. Find more about `FormField` [here on official doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField-class.html)